# Macros doesn't load on powerpoint startup

Tags: batch, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I have created a powerpoint macros to run a batch file when slideshow starts.
This is my code

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = _
        SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide Then
    Dim argh As Double
    argh = Shell("D:\test.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is after I close and open the power point and run slideshow the batch file doesn't run. After opening the slide after I press Alt+F11 and then return back to power point then running the slideshow loads the macro runs the batch file. I want to load the macros on the power point on startup. Any ideas where i made mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of VBA but not with PowerPoint so I don't have the full answer.

However, I can see that you are trying to detect a slide change event and then restricting  the action to only the first slide. I suspect the problem is that, on startup, the slide change event does not fire. so you never see a combination of slide change + first slide unless you move backwards from the second to the first slide. Obviously, you can prove that easily by going to the 2nd slide and then returning to the first.

The event that you want is called [SlideShowBegin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211566%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

UPDATE:
Getting `SlideShowBegin` to work is a little more complex than a simple sub because it needs to reference the `application` class. However, the following does work as you want it do.

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    If i <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    ' Insert any code you want activated on slide 1 after here
    MsgBox "This is slide 1"
End Sub
```

To use the other method, you need firstly to add the following in a normal module:

Option

```
Option Explicit
' Class1 is the name of the class module you create
Dim X As New Class1
Sub InitializeApp()
    Set X.App = Application
End Sub
```

Then you need to add a Class Module (must be called Class1 in this example) with the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Dim argh As Double
    Debug.Print "Slideshow started"
    argh = Shell("D:\test.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Clearly the first example is a lot easier to use!

UPDATE 2:

I did say I didn't use VBA in PP! I've discovered that PP doesn't have an autostart capability for VBA unless you access your code from an addin. The easiest way to get things to work is to change your code (in the ordinary module not the class module) to include a line to actually start the slide-show.

Then call that macro from developer toolbar (or create your own toolbar with the macro on it) so that it starts the slide show and calls your code.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @JulianKnight. I am new to this Power point VBA. I tried the syntax from the link you mentioned and modified the coding as below: `Private Sub App_SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    With Wn
        Dim argh As Double
        argh = Shell("D:\test.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    End With
End Sub` But nothing happens when I begin the slide show

Comment: No problem, see my update. To use SlideShowBegin, you have to create a class and reference it. That's because it is an application level event.

Comment: I thank you for your support @Julian. I am still facing the problem. The first option has same issue. After close open power point and start slide show, the macro doesn't run. But after opening the power point, then switching to and from the VBA window by pressing Alt+F11 twice the macro works OK. The second option I have created the macro as instructed but nothing happens. The Event is not loading up.

Comment: Try adding an ActiveX control to the first slide .. a text box or whatever.  Drag it off the slide so it's not visible to the viewer when the slide show runs.  As improbable as it may sound, this fixes a bug that can cause OnSlideShowPageChange not to fire.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Do I have to write any code for this ActiveX control or Just leave it as it is?

Comment: Just add it.  And a hint:  with a suggestion this simple, it'd be far faster and simpler to try it first before asking here and waiting for an answer, no?